# Expanding a number range from Access data entry form into table

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am building an inventory database that needs to track individual items. Each item has a unique number associated with it. However, we receive these items in bulk quantities, and distribute them likewise. I have set up a data entry form to input the start of the item number range, and the end of the item number range. For example, the item range would look something like this -- 1056-56701 through 1056-56800. The item number is always 4 digits followed by a dash and 5 digits. I am looking to expand the range that is put into my data entry form, so that each individual item number within the range is saved to my table. In this case-- 1056-56701, 1056-56702, 1056-56703, 1056-56704....156-56800. I also need to save the corresponding info for each item range as it is saved as an individual number. That would include things like 'date received', 'size', etc.

I have read some other responses to similar problems, but I still can't get this to function properly. Any thoughts?

Comment: If everything about the items in the range is the same except the 5 digit portion of the number, it shouldn't be necessary to store all that info multiple times. That would be a violation of the DRY principle. You might want to instead do something like have a "prefix" column (with the value "1056" in your example), and then have "suffixBegin" (such as 56701" and "suffixEnd" ("56800") columns.

Comment: The information for each item, arriving from the same batch, has identical information when we first receive them. So yes, the date received, size, etc. will be the same. But as we send out items, I need to be able to input corresponding info for each individual item. So, items from the same batch will end up with unique information that we need to be able to query.

Comment: In that case, you should have a related table that is populated with that unique data. The original table (sort of a lookup table) could hold the data common to the batch. The "Prefix" value could be the key in the original (master) table, and it could serve as the foreign key in the detail table.

Answer (score 1):

An example of the design you might need:

```
MASTER
------

Prefix      Int (primary key)
SuffixBegin String
SuffixEnd   String
ItemDescription String
DateReceived    Date
Size        String
. . . more columns for any other data common to the entire "batch"

DETAIL
------
ID  Int (primary key)
Prefix  Int (foreign key, related to the same-named column in the Master table)
Suffix  String (values such as "56701", "56702", etc.)
. . . more columns for whatever data you need to store about unique suffix items
```

You could then find data for a specific item something like this (pseudo-SQL, untested):

```
SELECT M.ItemDescription, D.SomeSuffixSpecificData
FROM MASTER M, DETAIL D
WHERE M.Prefix = (the Prefix you're interested in)
AND D.Suffix = (the Suffix you're interested in)
JOIN M.Prefix = D.Prefix
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function like this to list and add your items:

```
Public Function AddBulk(ByVal First As String, ByVal Last As String) As Integer

    Dim Items   As Integer
    Dim Item    As Integer
    Dim BulkId  As String

    ' Open your inventory table.
    ' Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select Top 1 * From Inventory")

    For Item = Split(First, "-")(1) To Split(Last, "-")(1)
        BulkId = Split(First, "-")(0) & "-" & Item
        Debug.Print Items, BulkId
        ' Insert code to add one record to your inventory table.
        ' rs.AddNew
        '     rs!BulkId.Value = BulkId
        '     rs!OtherField.Value = somevalue
        ' rs.Update
        Items = Items + 1
    Next

    ' rs.Close

    AddBulk = Items

End Function
```